# Which tensorflow-gpu version is compatible with Python 3.7.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

Actually, I am tired of getting "*ImportError: DLL load failed*"
in

- Windows 10
- CUDA Toolkit 10.0 (Sept 2018)
- Download cuDNN v7.6.0 (May 20, 2019) / v7.6.4
- tensorflow-gpu==1.13.1 / 1.13.2 / 1.14 / 1.15 / 2 (none of those were working)

Answer (score 1):

At the moment TensorFlow for GPU doesn't support Python 3.7 on Windows 10.

For a list of packages see "Package location" at the bottom of https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip?lang=python3

It lists the following for Windows:

Python 3.5 CPU-only https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-2.0.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl

Python 3.5 GPU support  https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-2.0.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl

Python 3.6 CPU-only https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/cpu/tensorflow-2.0.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl

Python 3.6 GPU support
https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/windows/gpu/tensorflow_gpu-2.0.0-cp36-cp36m-win_amd64.whl

Comment: suggest a preferable CUDA version and CUDNN

Answer (score 0):

I am using Windows 10 (64 bit) and I use these versions in a project and they work together:

```
python:3.7.4
tensorflow-gpu: 1.15
cuda:10.0
cudnn:7.6.5.32
numpy:1.17.4
```

Comment: in windows10x64,1909,nvidia GPU